# Jquery - Next IP Address

Tags: jquery, ip

I have a variable containing an IP Address.

`ip = '192.168.0.1'`

is there a way I can get the next IP Address ?

eg:

`nextip = getnextIP(ip)`

Comment: Tbh I don't believe there is.

Comment: Can it be converted to decimal, increased and then converted back ?

Comment: You can make your own without too much complexity - just need to check for overflow to move to the next part, eg: `ip = '192.168.0.1'; parts = ip.split("."); parts[3] = "" + ((parts[3] * 1) + 1);ip = parts.join("."); console.log(ip);` - I suspect converting to/from binary would be much easier though.  Edit: all javascript bitwise operations are in 32bits, so no probably not easier to convert to binary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work as expected:

```
function getnextIP(ip) {
    var parts = ip.split(".");
  var n = 0;
  for(var i=0; i<parts.length; i++) {
    var exp = parts.length-i-1;
    n+=parts[i] * Math.pow(2, exp*8)
  }
  n++;
  var bin = (n >>> 0).toString(2);
  var output = "";
  for(var i=0; i<32; i+=8) {
    var chunk = bin.substr(i,8);
    output+=parseInt(chunk, 2).toString()+".";
  }
  return output.substr(0,output.length-1);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This appears to do exactly what I need :)